# Best way to get a traded team? And will Pokémon at too high level rarely attack in battles?

Tags: pokemon-series

When I get a new Pokémon in the future I am planning on getting a traded team ( some Pokémon will be from my Pokémon X).

What are the best levels to ask for when getting a traded team (from gts, one Pokémon at a time)?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of getting traded team?

Will high level Pokémon that are given to the player listen to attacks?

Comment: Can't answer all, but a traded Pokémon will receive more experience and therefore grow faster. Also, if its level is too high, it will rarely listen. Most of the times, it'll just laze around (do nothing), rarely it will use a random move instead. It's been that way since Gen 1, and I'm not aware of any changes since then.

Answer (score 2):

The upside to traded Pokémon is they receive 1.5x experience from battles, or 1.7x if traded Pokémon is from a different language region cartridge.

The downside is, depending on how many badges/stamps you have, Pokémon only up to a certain level will listen to you. The possible options of what can happen, when a Pokémon is above the level you can command, depends on the generation of the game.
[image]
Another downside to having a traded team is that you can't rename the Pokémon.

[Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trade#Drawbacks_of_trading)